# CSS styling of <span> lost when wrapping it in <a>

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some warped text I'm using, generated by http://csswarp.eleqtriq.com/. It creates all the CSS and HTML for the warping, I'm wrapping the spans with an `<a>` tag whose class is used for styling and a jquery function.

The problem is, if I wrap the spans in the `<a>`, which I need because these warped words are my links, all the styling (positioning most importantly) just vanishes...If I remove the  wrapper from the spans, the style goes back to normal and it looks warped etc..

I've written the jsfiddle here for my problem, http://jsfiddle.net/WJDwP/2/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

`#warped>span[class^=w]:nth-of-type(n+0)`

to

`#warped span[class^=w]:nth-of-type(n+0)`

The > combinator selects only elements that are **direct descendants**. Once you put the `<a>` element between them, they're no longer direct descendants.

So instead we should use the good old descendant selector.

#### References

- [Child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Child_selectors)
- [Descendant selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Descendant_selectors)

Comment: Edited my answer to include the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand exactly what you're asking, it's a pretty simple fix - you just need to stack the #warped>span[class^=w] selector with one that incorporates the a the encloses the span, e.g.:

```
#warped a>span[class^=w]:nth-of-type(n+0), #warped>span[class^=w]:nth-of-type(n+0){    
     display:block; position:absolute;
     -moz-transform-origin:50% 100%; 
     -webkit-transform-origin:50% 100%; -o-transform-origin:50%
     100%; -ms-transform-origin:50% 100%; transform-origin:50% 100%; }
```

Here's the above in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hanleybrand/5RHvk/